# ES6 Polyfill for create-react-app isn't working

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, polyfills

I have created a new reactjs project using `create-react-app` and am finding it's not working on IE10 & IE9. I have done a lot of research and it led me to using polyfills, which I have done with many of my other Rails on React app, but I'm finding it not working with this project created via `create-react-app`.

Here's the error:

`SCRIPT5009: 'Map' is undefined`

I notice this error is related to ES6's `new Map()` function.

So, here's what I've done in my code in an attempt to make it work:

```
import './polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const app = (
  <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);

ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Polyfill.js:

```
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/fn/object/assign';
```

This isn't working. I'm not sure what else to try. I've tried a lot of other polyfill imports as well and continue to get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: @Deadron I'm using create-react-app, which uses webpack but I don't have access to override the config out of the box. That's why I can get my polyfills to work correctly when I create Rails on React apps because I make my own webpack config. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, I understand.

Comment: Did you check if the polyfills are in the resulting bundle? It may be a loading issue with the polyfills loading late.

Comment: I have it running as the first line on the index.js. It is compiling as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, seeing as though `create-react-app` is what's restricting me from controlling the webpack config, I decided to take a different approach and build a fresh react app using webpack 4. I followed this article, https://dev.to/saigowthamr/how-to-create-a-react-app-from-scratch-using-webpack-4-1909.

This allowed me more control over the webpack config and now the polyfill loaders are working.

Nevertheless, if anyone has an explanation as to why it wasn't working with create-react-app, I think it'd be helpful for the community to know.
Thanks!